pre-pull git-hook to run locally before pull
I'm experimenting with git-hooks and custom repo layout, where I need to prepare (update in a special way) sources before pulling changes from the remote.
I couldn't find the proper git-hook in the official list, and few related questions (like Is there any git hook for pull?) aren't applicable in my case, since they usually focus on the post-pull phase (i.e. can be handled with post-merge or a simlar hook), while post-fetch is the last phase when I can do my tricks with the sources :)
In short
The hook (script) should run evey time I pull, but before git applies the remote changes locally.
If the script fails (returns non-zero exit code) the pull should be rejected/canceled.
There are no git-hooks like pre-pull or post-fetch.
So far I see only two workarounds:

run extra script manually and then run git pull (both steps can be combined in one script)
add a git-alias to be invoked instead of pull

Some of the team-mates (including me) use TortoiseGit frequently, and mentioned workarounds won't align properly with this tool.
Git version: 2.41
OS: Windows 10
See also:

How would I write a pre-merge hook in Git?
Git pre-merge-commit hook : How do I ignore a file during a merge?


Clarification question: since git pull = git fetch + git merge, does it trigger the pre-merge-commit hook? (If it doesn't, that would be unfortunate, it really should!)

If yes, my second question is: can you clarify if & how the pre-merge-commit hook does not already do what you need?

@joanis, I haven't tried pre-merge-commit, but according to the documentation it is invoked after the merge has been carried out successfully and before obtaining the proposed commit log message to make a commit, so using this hook is too late in my case

Ah, OK, thanks for the clarification.

Have you find any solution? I need exactly the same)

@TimurGilauri , unfortunately no. And I doubt, this functionality can be natively implemented with current versions of git.
